Functions calling each other with a subset of types, leading to unintended intersection and never type
I've added a simplified version of my problem here
interface TEventAssetTypeA {
  assetType: 'a',
  data: {
    a : string
  }
}

interface TEventAssetTypeB {
  assetType: 'b',
  data:  {
    b : string
  } 
}

interface IStreamToAssetType {
  streama: TEventAssetTypeA
  streamb: TEventAssetTypeB
}

interface LogsEvent {
  logs: string
}

interface IStreamToLogType {
  streamc: LogsEvent
}

interface IStreamsToAlLEvents {
  streama: TEventAssetTypeA
  streamb: TEventAssetTypeB
  streamc: LogsEvent
}

const publishAsssetMessageToStream = <T extends keyof IStreamToAssetType, MA extends IStreamToAssetType[T]>(topic: T, message: MA) => publishToStreamCore<T, MA>({topic, message})

const publishToStreamCore = <T extends keyof IStreamsToAlLEvents, M extends IStreamsToAlLEvents[T]>({topic, message}:{topic: T, message: M}) => {
  console.log(topic, message)
}

publishAsssetMessageToStream('streama', {
    assetType: 'a',
    data: { a: '12313'}
})

I have a core function publishToStreamCore which maps messages to specific streams.
I have a higher level function which can publish a subset of those messages to their related substreams.
However I am getting the following error:
Type 'MA' does not satisfy the constraint 'IStreamsToAlLEvents[T]'.
  Type 'IStreamToAssetType[T]' is not assignable to type 'IStreamsToAlLEvents[T]'.
    Property 'streamc' is missing in type 'IStreamToAssetType' but required in type 'IStreamsToAlLEvents'.
      Type 'MA' is not assignable to type 'never'.
        The intersection 'TEventAssetTypeA & TEventAssetTypeB' was reduced to 'never' because property 'assetType' has conflicting types in some constituents.
          Type 'IStreamToAssetType[T]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
            Type 'TEventAssetTypeA | TEventAssetTypeB' is not assignable to type 'never'.
              Type 'TEventAssetTypeA' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2344)

Regardless, what is the best way to get around this?
I'm particularly surprised by the following line:
The intersection 'TEventAssetTypeA & TEventAssetTypeB' was reduced to 'never' because property 'assetType' has conflicting types in some constituents.
Why I am ending up with an intersection for MA at publishAsssetMessageToStream when I was hoping to have a union of either TEventAssetTypeA | TEventAssetTypeB?
Ideally, I would like to be specific in the core function, but only give higher level functions to other developers that would call this with a subset of the different events/topics.

Error message no longer matches what I am experiencing in my real codebase.

Because that's not the issue i'm having in my actual codebase, as I said?

And? Does it have the same error message? Is that reflective of my current code?

I produced a minimal example that produces the same error that I get in my codebase. Changing the example to produce to a different error to then be solved doesn't interest me, unless you want to show in an answer how they are actually the same problem regardless of the error message. EDIT: To be clear, if you want to insist on producing a different example that produces the same error message as I've provided, feel free to.

Additionally, the error message is not 'extraneous'. If you feel like rewriting the original example to give a different error makes it more solvable, then feel free to add that to an answer. 1st change your code to X, then we can solve it with Y.

Well then i'm happy to provide a slightly smaller example without those that produce a similar error, specially resulting in the intersection `The intersection 'TEventAssetTypeA & TEventAssetTypeB' was reduced to 'never' because property 'assetType' has conflicting types in some constituents. or some variation of that line.

Does this version isolate things more for you?

Or this

And does type TEventAssetTypes = TEventAssetTypeA | TEventAssetTypeB do anything?

Anyway I'm probably going to open as TS bug report about the basic issue here so that I can speak authoritatively when I answer. I've run into this sort of generic indexed access limitation before but I can't be sure it's already documented.

All right, so I filed ms/TS#58905 and it's a design limitation of TS. It's not worth the performance hit for TypeScript to compare the portion of IStreamsToAlLEvents  whose keys match those of IStreamToAssetType in order to see that those are identical. Instead it assumes that they are essentially unrelated types, and ends up performing the very safe but often annoying assignment check implemented in ms/TS#30769, which is where that intersection comes from. (see next comment)

(see prev comment) All known workarounds will end up mentioning that IStreamsToAlLEvents type in a place you don't want to, such as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Hope this helps for your particular use case — the problem may be that all properties of both IStreamToAssetType and IStreamsToAlLEvents are required, so the functions get confused because not all properties of the latter interface are included in the former (but the function types expect them to be).
I managed to get the error to go away if I refactor your code slightly.
First, for IStreamToAssetType, instead of an interface with required properties, change this to a type that picks from your IStreamsToAlLEvents interface only the subset of properties you want (which reading your question, seems more semantic):
type IStreamToAssetType = Pick<IStreamsToAlLEvents, 'streama' | 'streamb'>

Second, since your publishToStreamCore function will be called by publishAsssetMessageToStream, which will only take the subset type in its arguments and hence not have the whole interface, you need to make the types of this function partial, to indicate that you only expect a subset to be passed in:
const publishToStreamCore = <T extends keyof Partial<IStreamsToAlLEvents>, M extends Partial<IStreamsToAlLEvents[T]>>({topic, message}:{topic: T, message: M}) => {
  console.log(topic, message)
}

The whole code then (without errors) looks like this:
type BaseAssetType = {
  z?: string
}


/** Assets */
type AssetTypeAData = {
  a : string
}

type AssetTypeBData = {
  b : string
}


interface TEventAssetTypeA extends BaseAssetType {
  assetType: 'a',
  data: AssetTypeAData
}

interface TEventAssetTypeB extends BaseAssetType {
  assetType: 'b',
  data: AssetTypeBData
}

type TEventAssetTypes = TEventAssetTypeA | TEventAssetTypeB

type IStreamToAssetType = Pick<IStreamsToAlLEvents, 'streama' | 'streamb'>

/** Logs */
interface LogsEvent extends BaseAssetType {
  logs: string
}

type Topics = 'streama' | 'streamb' | 'streamc'

interface IStreamToLogType {
  streamc: LogsEvent
}

interface IStreamsToAlLEvents {
  streama: TEventAssetTypeA
  streamb: TEventAssetTypeB
  streamc: LogsEvent
}

const publishAsssetMessageToStream = <T extends keyof IStreamToAssetType, MA extends IStreamToAssetType[T]>(topic: T, message: MA) => publishToStreamCore<T, MA>({topic, message})

const publishToStreamCore = <T extends keyof Partial<IStreamsToAlLEvents>, M extends Partial<IStreamsToAlLEvents[T]>>({topic, message}:{topic: T, message: M}) => {
  console.log(topic, message)
}

publishAsssetMessageToStream('streama', {
    assetType: 'a',
    data: { a: '12313'}
})

Hope that helps!
